# learning how to sql stuck on basic query

Tags: sql

I have a problem that reads; display all details of flight.Display flights b2 and b4 from s3 and s5 only if the capacity is not equal to 100. Capacity must be displayed with 'people' appended to it.

I don't understand how to display for flights b2 and b4 from s3 and s5 and any attempt i've made hasn't worked. any help would be appreciated!
This is what i have so far:

[image: table structure image]

`Select FLIGHTID, PLANEID, CAPACITY || 'PEOPLE'
    FROM FLIGHT
    WHERE
    AND CAPACITY<>100;`

Comment: What are b2,b4,s3,s5. Your question is not clear.

Comment: Share the table structure and sample data. It isn't clear what you require.

Comment: I've attached the relevant table :)

Comment: what error your facing now .can you show me the error ?@Marheasher

Comment: try this Select FLIGHTID, PLANEID, CAPACITY || 'PEOPLE'
    FROM FLIGHT
    WHERE
    CAPACITY<>100;

Comment: what is the data type of your CAPACITY column ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query:

```
Select FLIGHTID, PLANEID, CAPACITY || 'PEOPLE' 
FROM FLIGHT
WHERE CAPACITY <> 100;
```

No need to use `AND` if you are having a single condition.

Comment: i need to display all the coloumns for only the fields b2 and b4 from s3 and s5...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is you want

```
Select FLIGHTID, PLANEID, CAPACITY || 'PEOPLE' 
FROM FLIGHT
WHERE
FLIGHTID IN ('B2','B4')
AND
PLANEID IN ('S3','S5')
AND
CAPACITY <> 100;
```

Comment: This somewhat works but doesn't display all the results

Comment: all the result means what you mean ? @Marheasher

Comment: post your expected results . we will work through it further